# Безопасно ли добавлять ssh для Docker up?

Tags: docker

в общем склонировал прорект на Docker
Installation:

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:team/devxxx.git yourFolder
```

так вот он требует `id_rsa`

```
cp ~/.ssh/id_rsa ./.ssh

cp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ./.ssh



    #mkdir ./yourFolder/.ssh
copy ssh keys (id_rsa, id_rsa.pub) to ./yourFolder/.ssh

    cd yourFolder
    docker-compose build
    docker-compose up 

cp ~/.ssh/id_rsa ./.ssh

cp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ./.ssh
```

если выполнять команд типа не могут эти rsa куда еще попасть?

```
docker exec -it yourFolder_www_1 '/var/www/scripts/install'
```

Comment: На это вам никто не ответит однозначно. Зависит от того, что за образ и что в нем за программы. Легко можно сделать образ, который будет отсысать ваш ключ по сети.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переименуйте файлы ключей и сгенерируйте другие ключи специально для использования в вашем контейнере командой `ssh-keygen -t rsa`